# Solve $y'(t)=\operatorname{sin}(t)+\int_0^t y(x)\operatorname{cos}(t-x)dx$ by Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

**Question:**

> Solve $y'(t)=\operatorname{sin}(t)+\int_0^t y(x)\operatorname{cos}(t-x)dx$ such that $y(0)=0$

**My try:**
I applied Laplace transform on both sides of the equation.

$
sL\{y(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2+1}+L\{cos(t)*y(t)\} \implies sL\{y(t)\}=\frac{1}{s^2+1}+L\{cos(t)\}\times L\{y(t)\} $
$\implies L\{y(t)\} = \frac{s^2-1}{(s^3-s-1)(s^2+1)} $ (*)

Now, I'm stuck on applying the inverse Laplace transform on (*) to find $y(t)$.

Any idea?

Comment: you made a mistake its finally $\frac 1  {s^3}$ whixh i simple to find the inverse  transform

Comment: @OlivierOloa If there was an option to accept both of your answers, I would definitely choose it. But I'm afraid there isn't. But your hint was also nice. So, Thank you for your answer :) The upvote is done :) Sorry i didn't remember to do it ...

Comment: @Arman Malekzadeh Thank you! I just gave you a hint, didn't want to solve it for you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sL\{y(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2+1}+L\{cos(t)*y(t)\} $

$sL\{y(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2+1}+L\{y(t)\}*\frac s {s^2+1} $

$L\{y(t)\}(s- \frac s {s^2+1})= \frac{1}{s^2+1}$

Here you made a mistake I guess

$L\{y(t)\}( \frac {s^3-s+s} {s^2+1})= \frac{1}{s^2+1} $

$L\{y(t)\}= \frac{1}{s^3} $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You are on the right track. But please check your results, since from your identity
$$
sL\{y(t)\}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}+L\{cos(t)\}(s)\times L\{y(t)\} (s)
$$ using
$$
L\{cos(t)\}(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+1}
$$ I rather get
$$
L\{y(t)\}(s)=\frac1{s^3}
$$ which is now standard to solve.